# Public delegate is not accessible from another class

Tags: c#

I'm watching a Scott Alan's course on Pluralsight about generic in C#. In the video he create a new static class for extensions methods and he put inside this class a public delegate, it looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ScottAllen.Generics
{
    public static class BufferExtensions
    {

        public delegate void Printer(object data);

        public static void Dump<T>(this IBuffer<T> buffer, Printer print)
```

In `Program.cs` I want to use this delegate, and in the video I see that in the `Main` method he just writes

`Printer print...` and the compilers recognizes `Printer` however when I try it, the `Printer` is underlined with red and I'm able to use it only with the fully qualified name `ScottAllen.Generics.BufferExtensions.Printer`. I tried to clean the project, re build it and so on but it seems that this is not the issue. The `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScottAllen.Generics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScottAllen.Generics.BufferExtensions.Printer ..
```

So basically my question is, why at the video he can just use `Printer` and I can't and what need to be changed in order to access `Printer` without using the fully qualified name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `Printer` definition outside of the class:

```
namespace ScottAllen.Generics
{
  public delegate void Printer(object data);
  ...
}
```

Then you will be able to use `Printer` type without any prefix if you are in `ScottAllen.Generics` namespace or if `using ScottAllen.Generics;` is included.

Comment: Yeap, I totally missed that. I appolagize to `Dusan` indeed there was something that I overlooked and it was the fact that the delegate is defined outside the class! Now it's all fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in same namespace as BufferExtensions, this is enough:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     BufferExtensions.Printer ..
```

Since the `Printer` is declared inside `BufferExtensions` class,
there is no way to leave out `BufferExtensions` when specifying `Printer` type.

Alternatively, you can give the alias to `BufferExtensions.Printer` using directive:

```
...
using Printer = BufferExtensions.Printer;
...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Printer ..
```

Comment: I would agree with you and I wouldn't even post this question if the tutorial wasn't pretty straight-forward up untill now and I see that indeed the `Printer` is used on it's own even withouth `BufferExtensions`. I guess, for now I'll leave the topic as it is. But if you got around this tutorial you may see for yourself. I'm pretty sure that  I haven't missed anything. It must be something that is not directly connected with generics so it's not explained in the tutorial but I can see it working as described in my OP. The version of .NET is 4.5 used from Scott Alan.

Comment: Sorry, as you can see at `Igor`'s answer, I really did missed something important. However he pointed out how to make it work so I'll accept his answer but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In another class you need to type at least the static method's name:

```
BufferExtensions.Printer myPriner;
```

In C# 6, you'll be able to do that with "using static" (see [here](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/07/c-6-0-using-static/))

```
using System.Console;

public void DoSomething()
{
  WriteLine("Line 1");
  WriteLine("Line 2");
  WriteLine("Line 3");
}
```